# How can i loop through different variables when using multiple hosts for deployment?

Tags: ansible

Currently i am thinking of a solution on how to loop through a variable file and use the saved variables in the variable file which is defined in

`/roles/webservers for each different host` (In the case of each host has it's own unique properties and variables). The variables are located in `/roles/webservers/variables/webserver_variables.yml`

**For example**

```
host1 needs the following attributes from the file:  
  - fantastic_value a: raccoon  
 - fantastic_value b: duck  
host2 needs the following attributes from the file:  
 - fantastic_value a: sheep  
 - fantastic_value b: cow
```

The above is purely fiction to illustrate my point.

These variables are defined in a variable file in the specific role i use (web servers) for my Linux webservers.

How can i make it work so that host1 and host2 get the appropriate values?

I tried looping through a list with `with_items` however that did not work out.

Comment: Hi..WC to SO! Kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to post proper OP!

Comment: thank you @error404 i will read it through!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way to achieve this is to have the variable and value in yaml file. The yaml file name should be same as host name inside the *host_vars* folder.

Below is the sample directory layout

```
|- inventory           # inventory file for servers
|- group_vars/
|  |- group1.yml       # here we assign variables to particular groups
|  `- group2.yml
`- host_vars/
   |- host1.yml        # here we assign variables to particular host
   `- host2.yml
```

host_vars/host1.yml

```
---
fantastic_value_a: 'raccoon'
fantastic_value_b: 'duck'
```

host_vars/host2.yml

```
---
fantastic_value_a: 'sheep'
fantastic_value_b: 'cow'
```

For more information check this [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html)

Comment: Thank you! That is what i am looking for!